# Python argparse accept variable argument (even flags)

Tags: python

I have the following

```
p = ThrowingArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('action', type=str, choices=actions)
p.add_argument('args', nargs='*')
```

This is part of a multi level application. In level one, the command I care about is of the format `command other-things-that-will-be-parsed-by-the-sub-module` (for example `get user john`). So I'd except to get `action = "get"` and `args = ["user", "john"]`.

So far so good. However, if I include a flag, all hell breaks loose (`get user john --detailed`). This will return a `None`. But I want to get the same as before: `action = "get"` and `args = ["user", "john", "--detailed"]`.

Why is this failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `nargs=argparse.REMAINDER`. Please see https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs.